# same elements are ready find which on is chosen for deletion

Tags: javascript, jquery

a foreach loop is produce many element with same class in a div(the div is curectly present with id "#show_case" )

```
foreach ($messages as $key => $value) { ?>
        <div class="message">
            <p class="username"><?php echo $value['username']; ?></p> <span>say:</span>
            <p class="text"> <?php echo $value['message']; ?></p>
            <p class="message_id"><?php echo $value['message_id']?></p>
        </div> <?php }
}
```

i built a right click context menu that have a delete button that have id #delete and do this code when  is clicked

```
$('#delete').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $('.message_id').text();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/chat.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            method: "delete",
            id: id,
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert('successfully deleted');
        }
    });

});
```

delete button is here (it is a right click contextmenu will be avilibe after right click on the element)

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <button id="delete">delete</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

i tryed

```
 var id = $('.message_id').text();
```

for get id but it return all elements ids by class message_id ... i what just the id of element that clicked by delete button

Comment: You will have to store clicked element in a variable on right click and reset it reference on click of anything except context menu

Comment: Where is this delete button? I suspect you want to use something like `closest` method, but it's hard to tell without knowing the DOM layout.

Comment: @wmorrell `delete` option is in context menu. So closest will not work as context menu will be common and independent of structure

Comment: Then you will probably want to use `closest` at the time of building the context menu, and pass the contents of `.message_id` to the context menu to attach to the button.

Answer (score 0):

where is your `#delete` button?
If the delete button contains `.message_id`, you can use

```
var id = $(this).find('.message_id').text();
```

Comment: i tryied it rerutn empety you can see delete code on post

Comment: @moh  can you create a fiddle example link of your problem with your rendered html on browser (not with foreach code)

Comment: my project is running here 
here http://myarch.duckdns.org/
you can check page soruce "chat.js" file 
i provided ****** CHECK MEEEEE***** comment
above failed code

Comment: "This site can’t be reached", please check the site again

Answer (score 0):

I have created a [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/xk9rux1q/) to get the `id` of the element on `right click` and save this id into an input or hidden element so that the can be retrieved in different functions. Here is the code from the DEMO:

**HTML:**

```
<h3>Right click on below messages</h3>
<div class="message" style="border:1px dotted">
            <p class="username">Username 1</p> <span>say:</span>
            <p class="text"> text 1</p>
            <p class="message_id">1</p>
        </div>
<br>        
<div class="message" style="border:1px dotted">
            <p class="username">Username 2</p> <span>say:</span>
            <p class="text"> text 2</p>
            <p class="message_id">2</p>
        </div>
<br>        
Selected message id: 
<input type="text" id="selected_message_id" />
```

**JS:**

```
$(function () {
    $(".message").contextmenu(function() {
    alert("clicked message id = "+$(this).find('.message_id').html());
    $('#selected_message_id').val($(this).find('.message_id').html());
    return false;
  });
});
```

Now in your below function, you can get the `message_id` like this:

```
$('#delete').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $('#selected_message_id').val();//get the message_id from the hidden/text input
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/chat.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            method: "delete",
            id: id,
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert('successfully deleted');
        }
    });

});
```